# n- regression on n-dimensional lists

Tags: python, regression

I have two lists of n by m-dimensions and would like to run independent regressions on them :

Given two lists :

`l = [[l1, l2, l3, l4, l5],[l6, l7, l8, l9, l10]...]`&

`n = [[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5], [n6, n7, n8, n9, n10] ...]`

I'd like to regress `[l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]` with `[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]` and `[l6, l7, l8, l9, l10]` with `[n6, n7, n8, n9, n10]` (...) and save the beta values to into an empty list.

I originally attempted to simply use :

`regression.linear_model.OLS(l, sm.add_constant(n)).fit()`

but it doesn't seem to exhibit the desired behaviour.

Doing

`[regression.linear_model.OLS(l[x], sm.add_constant(n[x]).fit() for x in range(0, len(l)]`

however takes too long to run as I have a over 80000 regressions to run.

Comment: What **exactly** is your question? You seem to have a working answer that you want to be faster, is that your question? The more specific your question the better chance you will get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are bootstrapping, yea?  This seems to work fairly fast for me.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

#Simulating your data
f = lambda x: 2*x+3 + np.random.normal(0,0.5)
X = [np.random.rand(5) for i in range(80000)]
Y = [f(x) for x in X]

#Store coefficients here
models = []

#Loop through the data
for x,y in zip(X,Y):

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)

    #Add the coefficient and the intercept to the list
    models.append([slope,intercept])

np.array(models[:5])
>>>array([[ 2.  ,  3.47],
          [ 2.  ,  2.66],
          [ 2.  ,  2.94],
          [ 2.  ,  3.01],
          [ 2.  ,  2.75]])
```